# How to create new method for generics in ggplot2?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to create a new guide for ggplot2 and in the process I had to create a new method for the ggplot2 generic `guide_train()`. In my code I have

```
# constructor function which returns an object of 
# class = c("guide", "colorbar2", "colorbar")
#' @export
guide_colourbar2 <- function(...)  { 
    # things 
}

# methods
#' @export
guide_train.colorbar2 <- function(guide, scale) { 
     # things 
}
```

The problem is that now CMD check complains that there's no documentation for `guide_train.colorbar2`. I gather this is because roxygen2 exports it as regular function (`export(guide_train.colorbar2)`). But since this method is internal to ggplot2 workings, it makes no sense to document it.

Creating my own generic dispatch changes my NAMESPACE so that the new method is exported as `S3method(guide_train,colorbar2)` and solves the CMD check warning, but now the new guide doesn't work. Using it throws

> Error in UseMethod("guide_train") :    no applicable method for
>   'guide_train' applied to an object of class "c('guide', 'colorbar2')"

In [this](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/roxygen2/vignettes/namespace.html) vignette it says that "If you want to add a new method to an S3 generic, import it with @importFrom pkg generic." But adding `@importFrom ggplot2 guide_train` to my function definition makes my package fail to load with error

> Error : object ‘guide_train’ is not exported by 'namespace:ggplot2'

This is the first time I'm working with the S3 system, but it seems to me that the correct way would be the `@importFrom` way and the real problem is that ggplot2 doesn't export the generic. Is that the case or there are other problems with my code?

Comment: I don't think there is a generic based on a search of the repo. It just seems to use "." in the naming pattern.

Comment: I think this is the generic, right? https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/blob/8778b48b37d8b7e41c0f4f213031fb47810e70aa/R/guides-.r#L297

Comment: `guide_train` is an internal function of `ggplot2`. It is not exported, thus you can not access it when `ggplot2` is loaded. Does the function work as a method in your R session? I think, you should create your own generic function. If you want to export the method, you should document it. Ofcourse, you can use keyword "internal" (`#' @keywords internal`) to hide the documentation.

Comment: Defining `guide_train.colourbar2` and exporting it works well, yes. I don't want to export the method for the user to use, but it seems that I need to export it for `ggplot2` to use (since the call is made within `ggplot2`). I tried defining my own generic, but that fails.
`ggplot2` defines `guide_train.colorbar` and exports it, but with no documentation. That's what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: Is the question just about documentation then? Can you reword in that case?

Comment: Also see [this scale extension](https://github.com/thomasp85/ggraph/blob/master/R/edge_colourbar.R) by a `ggplot2` contributor for an example. (But note there [may be issues for some users](https://github.com/thomasp85/ggraph/issues/75)).

Comment: Since `ggplot2` doesn't document these methods, I thought that it made no sense that CRAN made me document them and I thought I was doing something wrong. 
Thanks for the `ggraph` example, then.